# php - check if value is in csv-file

Tags: php, csv

im trying to check if two php-values are in one line in the csv fiel.

csv:

> password, name
>
> 12345, max
>
> 44444, emil

but when my variable is $password="123" and in the csv file its "12345" he accepts it.

But, how can i check if its 100% equals? I dont understand why "123" is enough?

```
$search      = $name;
$search2     = $password;
$lines       = file('Benutzer.csv');
$line_number = false;
$line_number2 = false;

while (list($key, $line) = each($lines) and !$line_number) {

$line_number = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE );
$line_number2 = (strpos($line, $search2) !== FALSE );

}

if($line_number and $line_number2 ){
header('Location: alert_anmelden_erfolgreich.php');
 }
  else{
    header('Location: alert_anmelden_NICHT_erfolgreich.php');
   }
```

Comment: use `===` or `strcmp` instead of `strpos`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) looks for a substring in a string. So first things first"

```
strpos('12345','345')
```

will return `2` since the substring exists starting at that index. In your case:

```
strpos('12345','123')
```

or really `1,12,123,1234,12345` will all return the position 0. Now, when equating as you do to `false` you're essentially getting:

```
0==`false`
```

which is of course true because `0` an be casted to `false`. As @u_mulder, commented use of the full type equality operator `===` would fix that, but still won't solve your problem!. What you want is `strcmp`, which will return `0(false)` only if the strings are identical, and can be used like you wanted. You could also use `===` or `==` between the strings since you don't care about 'less/more' string.

```
if( $line === $search )
```